# What to do with code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

So I just started programming, and the first app I made is supposed to print 'Hello World!' on my screen. So I copied the code

```
#include  <iostream>
int main()
{
    std:: cout << "Hello World!" << std:: endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But now I'm wondering: Where can I see it? Where can I see 'Hello World!' being printed on a screen?

p.s. - I'm using Microsoft Visual c++ 2010 express

Comment: Press ctrl+F5 to launch it.

Comment: Did you try running the executable produced by compiling your program?

Comment: Obviously in its console !

Comment: If it compiles, [ship it!](http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Guide-Successful-Software-Projects/dp/0974514047)

Comment: You should probably learn a thing or two about compilation...

Comment: It seems that somebody has copied your code and made a [video for you](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRcoKAkg8mI). Nice!

Comment: @sehe You must be a Haskell programmer.

Comment: and then you'll also want to know this: [Why is the console window closing immediately without displaying my output?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8868338)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to

```
#include  <iostream>
int main()
{
    std:: cout << "Hello World!" << std:: endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

What will this do that it will ask for a character input from you before exiting the console.

Comment: It runs even better if you put the `getchar()` call *before* the `return` statement :-P

Comment: In fact, use `std::cin.get();` - seems more idiomatic

Comment: That should be `std::getchar` in C++.

Comment: Err, actually, the best solution would be `std::cin.ignore()`.

Comment: @Saksham [so] is not about being really fast or first.

Comment: Yes, actually, @CodyGray is right. `std::cin.ignore()` would be better

Answer (score -1):

use function named `getch();`aft program waits to recieve keyboard's character. therefor you can see your output on console

Comment: C++ standard doesn't have any mention of `getch()` function.