# Debugging when my code is started by external program with Process.Start()

Tags: c#, debugging, process.start, external-process

Suppose I have a C# WinForms application and it is started by external program simply by using `Process.Start(MyModule.exe)`.

I've tried to debug my code by using **My project properties**->**Debug**->**Start Action**->**Start external program** (with setting proper **Working directory** of course).

My enother attempt was **Debug**->**Attach to process**

**UPDATE:** Both my module and external program use one resource. So external program releases it, then calls Process.Start(), waits for my process to exit ans then capture the resource again. So I can't attach when your program is already running.

Both of them failed - breakpoint in **Program.cs** was never hit.

So, how can I debug my code in such circumstances?

Comment: I *think* **Attach to Process** should work if you attach when your program is already running. Did you attach to your application, or to the other program that starts it?

Comment: I attach to external program. I've updated my post for some information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways I know of to easily solve this problem. The first way is have your program request a debugger attach to it as the first thing it does in Main via [`Debugger.Launch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Debugger.Launch();

    //Rest of your code here
}
```

This will make a dialog like the following show up
[image]

This will allow you to attach to your running visual studio or start a new instance.

The other way to solve this when you can't use the previous method (for example I don't think it works inside services) is put a loop at the start of your code that will loop forever until a debugger is attached, this gives you enough time to do the "Attach to process" method you tried earlier without letting the program progress.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(!Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); //Sleep 1 second and then check again.
    }

    //Rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: For my interest: is Debugger.Launch() or Debugger.IsAttached() only active if the code is compiled in Debug Configuration?

Comment: @this.myself Both of those methdos are active in release mode, it is some of the functions in [`Debug`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.debug(v=vs.110).aspx) not `Debugger` that don't get compiled during a release. This is done through the [`Conditional`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute) attribute, if you right click the method and do `Navigate to->Metadata` you can see if the method you are wondering about has the `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different methods you can use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` or `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` The first will attach a debugger (letting you choose which) and then do nothing. In the case where one is already attached nothing will happen.
The latter will do exactly as `Launch` in the case no debugger is attached and will serve as a break point if one is attached.

So simply write `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` where you want your break point to be.

That will result in a dialog asking you how you wish to debug the program (which of course also means your should remove the line when your done debugging)

In the dialog choose the appropriate instance of VS (or create a new) and the simply continue debugging as usual

Comment: [`Debugger.Break()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.100).aspx) - is corrent syntax, but it's not working for me

Comment: what's not working? is the program build with release or debug build?

Comment: Debug. I've tried **Start external program** approach - after clicking corresponding button in external program my module simply opens..

Comment: Just start the program that calls `Process.Start(...)`