# Console window just closes? c#

Tags: c#

Soooo this program seems logical, and I've been able to make programs with the same idea in c++ and java 
whenever i run it everything just closes all of a sudden... perhaps i just got something downloaded wrong

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* 
            int[] numbahs= new int[5];
            numbahs[0] = 4;
            numbahs[1] = 3;
            Console.WriteLine(numbahs[1].ToString());

            string[] cow = new string[] { "pee", "poop" };
            foreach (string pee in cow)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(pee);
            }
            */

            int x;
            int y;
            Console.WriteLine("enter x:");
            x = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("enter y:");
            y = Console.Read();
            int z = (x > y)? 8 : 2;
            Console.WriteLine("x:{0} y:{1} z:{2}",x ,y, z);
            if (z > x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("yoyo");
                Console.Read();
            }
            else { Console.WriteLine("hihi"); }

            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WriteLine("yoyo".."hihi".... ah... Good old times :D

Comment: What are you doing to stop the program terminating? Once it reaches the end of the program, surely it terminates. Why would you expect it not to do so?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Presumably the `Console.Read`.

Comment: Attach a debugger. Step through the code. This will show you when the application is terminating and why.

Answer (score 5):

Use Console.ReadLine

```
    int x;
    int y;

    Console.WriteLine("enter x:");
    x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("enter y:");
    y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int z = (x > y)? 8 : 2;

    Console.WriteLine("x:{0} y:{1} z:{2}",x ,y, z);
    if (z > x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("yoyo");
    }
    else { Console.WriteLine("hihi"); }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: @B.K., actually this is the correct solution, yours is not.

Comment: @B.K.: This will work. The mistake in the original code was to assume that `Console.Read()` would read and return an int when it actually returns the next character entered. Entering a few digits and a newline would result in all the `Console.Read()` calls returning and the program terminating.

Comment: @B.K both will work. Console.Readline() will block until you type a string and hit enter, while console.ReadKey() until you press any key.

Comment: wow thanks I'm sorry for not researching enough before I posted, I am going through these microsoft virtual academy tutorials and never knew about the int.Parse thing

Comment: @DimitrisFousteris - This answer could be much better if you explain what is going on and why this is the answer.

Comment: @walther You're right, I misunderstood your initial response.

Answer (score -1):

Add a `Console.ReadLine()` instead of Console.Read.

The correct explanation is here : [Why is the console window closing immediately without displaying my output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868338/why-is-the-console-window-closing-immediately-without-displaying-my-output)

Comment: There's a `Console.Read` at the end.

Comment: I didn't downvote (even tho I probably should), but your solution doesn't solve or explain anything.