# C#: Console.WriteLine not printing out results

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the following bit of code to print out the "sum" to the console, it compiles fine and everything but never prints out the sum. Can someone give me a hint please? Thanks.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Not sure how to call "ArraySum" from here.
    }

    public void ArraySum()
    {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int sum = 0;

        foreach (int x in arr)
        {
            sum += x;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum); 
    }
```

EDIT: Sorry for not posting the whole code, but yeah. Basically I'm not sure how to call the method from main and have it print out the sum.

Comment: Do you ever call `ArraySum`?

Comment: I think the duplicate is wrong. He didn't say it closes before he can see it, he said it just doesn't print.

Comment: You either don't call this method from your `main()`, or the console window disappears before you get a chance to read the output. See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868338/why-is-the-console-window-closing-immediately-without-displaying-my-output) for the latter. If that doesn't apply, read [ask] and provide a [mcve] that contains enough code to properly demonstrate the issue.

Comment: As @CodeCaster said OP is probably posting outside of `main()` it prints properly if that is done.

Comment: That was Carcigenicate's observation, @confusedandamused. It's equally plausible as the console window closing, thus the OP not being able to read the output. It's off-topic at the moment either way. I'll happily reopen it if the OP provides additional detail; as currently stated it's unanswerable and will remain closed as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @val did you try debugging?

Comment: Ah sorry didn't even see that above @CodeCaster - need more coffee :)

Comment: @rory.ap I think the latest community edition of VS just sends you to SO in a browser window when you hit F9. That's my best guess.

Comment: Everything in your program is a constant. Why are you writing this code instead of just putting `Console.WriteLine(15)` in your `Main`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate h-how do I call it good sir?

Comment: @DourHighArch homework I guess... pls help.

Comment: @CodeCaster added more info, sorry.

Comment: @ValeriLagunov Are you asking how to call a function? You should review the basics if you don't know that (no offense). You call a function like: `ArraySum()`.

Comment: `var program = new Program(); program.ArraySum();` - your title is very misleading.

Comment: @AntP thank you... that worked.

Comment: @Carcigenicate sorry, one of the repliers told me to use "var program = new Program(); program.ArraySum()" which worked but I don't think I've seen an implementation like this anywhere before (online coruses etc.).

Comment: @ValeriLagunov The way you call a function is by ending it with parenthesis that contain the arguments to the function. How that function is namespaced depends on the language (I don't know C# honestly). I would have expected you to be able to call `ArraySum` without instantiating a `Program`,  since it seems `Program` is the the main class, but that could be a difference between C# code and similar Java code, which I'm thinking of. levelonehuman's answer below seems to suggest that I'm right though.

Comment: Whoops, nvm, I missed the fact that `ArraySum` isn't `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work like you've got it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ArraySum();
}
```

But if you try to compile this, you'll see an error message similar to `an object reference is required ... Program.ArraySum()`.

Why?

`Main()` is `static` - simply, this means you don't create an instance of it - there's only one. So in addition to the above, update `ArraySum()` to be `static` as well:

```
static void ArraySum()
{
    //your code
}
```

and it should work like you expect it to.

Edit:

As an aside of sorts, [this tutorial](http://scottlilly.com/learn-c-by-building-a-simple-rpg-index/) helped me out a lot when I first started, and I'd highly recommend it.

Comment: @L.B Certainly, but that was covered in the comments so I just added the other side of things.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very useful. Will definitely check out the RPG tutorial btw.