# "Hello world" c# program appear for a split of a second with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

The code is correct I checked, and there is no real problem with my PC, my hardware is a bit old but it can do the job, so I'm guessing it's the settings of Visual Studio, I use the 2017 community edition and the solution is a consol application. the solution runs but I don't see my msg or anything, just the consol opening and closing real fast

Comment: Could you explain better what you mean and add a question? At the moment I have no idea what you mean. Appear where? Please edit the question with more details.

Comment: If you use C#, please check this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio

Comment: I'd guess that you don't halt the console in any way with something like `Console.ReadKey();`. Once the `Main` method ends then the console closes, this is normal.

Comment: Try to run without debugging, Ctrl+F5 or add `Console.ReadKey()` in the end of your main class

Comment: Seems like a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8868338/1997232).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running the application in debug, without something to prevent it to close as soon as the job gets done.
Basically, your code executes, and the application shuts because there is nothing else left to do.
Two solutions:

- do as Štěpán Šubík recommands : put a `Console.ReadKey()`;
- start the application without debugging (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or menu *Debug -> Start Without Debugging*).

In both case, the console won't close itself automatically :).

Answer (score 0):

check if you did everything correctly.
File -> New -> New Project
Visual C# on the left side,
Console Application,
give it a name and location.

Then write this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hello_world
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The outpot is Hello World
It should stay in console and wait for pressing any button e.g.: k.

This works for my Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 and I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work for you.