# Continuation is not displaying Result

Tags: c#

The Following code does not display the resutl:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task<DayOfWeek> taskA = Task.Run(() => DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
    Task continuation = taskA.ContinueWith(antecedent => Console.WriteLine("\n\nToday is {0}.", antecedent.Result));
}
```

This can be solved by:

```
try
{
      taskA.Wait();
      continuation.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
  foreach (var ex in ae.InnerExceptions)
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the console window closing immediately without displaying my output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868338/why-is-the-console-window-closing-immediately-without-displaying-my-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Console.ReadKey()` at the and of `Main` because you program exits before task prints anything.

Comment: Nice! Thank you.