# continuing program after entering integer user input c#

Tags: c#, integer, user-input

when i run my code, my console suddenly shuts off after a number is entered into the console.

```
int age;
        Console.WriteLine("How old are you?");

        age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("You are {0} years old", age);
```

can someone help me with this problem? I never get to see the end result because it just shuts off. there are no errors that pop up but it is getting quite frustrating.

Comment: Add a Console.ReadLine() at the end. The program exits when it does all operations, so just make it wait for user to hit enter.

Comment: Well, if your program ends (and if you did not start your program from an already open cmd window), it will close the program (console) window. To prevent the program from ending (and thus preventing the window from closing), add a `Console.ReadLine()` as the last line in your main method (i guess). If you are interested in knowing what _Console.ReadLine()_ does, check its documentation...

Comment: Try CTRL+F5 when running in Visual Studio.

Comment: I prefer `Console.ReadKey()` over `Console.ReadLine()` as it allows the user to hit any key to terminate the program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the console window closing immediately once displayed my output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868338/why-is-the-console-window-closing-immediately-once-displayed-my-output)

Answer (score 0):

Add `Console.ReadLine()` or `Console.ReadKey()` as your last line.

Answer (score 0):

When the execution of the program is done, the console windows closes. You have to make a way for a program to keep running so the console window stays open. Usually, this is achieved by adding

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

or

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

in the end of your code. This way the console is waiting for your input and it stays open. As soon as you hit any key in keyboard (in case of `Console.ReadKey()`) or *Enter key* (in case of `Console.ReadLine()`), execution is done and the console window exits.