# How to use ILoggerFactory and log to the console

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, loggerfactory

I created a simple console application in .Net Core 3.1.
I want to create a logger and print it to the console.

I have the following code

```cs
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole());
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(nameof(Program));
        logger.LogInformation("some logging info");
    }
}
```

when I run the command **dotnet run** nothing is printed.

Is there something else I need to configure?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 this might be helpful

Comment: I already read this article. I try to copy the code there but I still not printing to the console.

Comment: @Yanivdaye your code work to me ! , try to add Console.ReadLine(); after the LogInformation line and you will see the result in the console window

Comment: It works, Why I should add Console.ReadLine() to see the result in the console window?

Comment: Because it's finished. When console applications have completed executing and return from their main method, the associated console window automatically closes. This is expected behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868338/why-is-the-console-window-closing-immediately-once-displayed-my-output/8868363