# Task.Run(() => myMethod()) is not working unless I use wait() method as well

Tags: c#

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/course/parallel-csharp/learn/lecture/11126262#notes) on Udemy. The instructor has put this simple code on screen. And it's working on the instructor screen.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => Print());
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Print());

        //Print();
    }

    private static void Print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing is happening for me. I don't see the numbers on the screen. Am I missing something? However, this code works, i.e. if I add the wait() method.

```
var t = Task.Run(() => Print());
t.Wait();
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: The program exits first..? Replace the Wait with a `Thread.Sleep(Timespan.FromSeconds(20))` and compare.. If it’s not “fire and *really* forget”, the result generally must be waited.

Comment: Your link doesn't work by the way, since it requires login.

Comment: Add `Console.ReadKey()` at the end of `Main` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the console window closing immediately once displayed my output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868338/why-is-the-console-window-closing-immediately-once-displayed-my-output)

Comment: @Sinatr I just notice that there's a `Console.ReadKey()` line that I overlooked because I didn't know it has any impact on the way the code works.  Sorry, I'm in the early stage of understanding how asynchronous programming. The author didn't explain that.

Comment: @user2864740 it was confusing to me because `await` is normally next to the operation supposed to be asynchronous. I didn't know that the `Console.ReadKey()` would have the same effect. I googled like crazy but all I could find is that I had to add `wait()` for it to work. I've a long way to go with asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Main` method returns and the program exits before the task started running.

Adding `.Wait` prevents this, since the `Main` method will now wait for the task to complete. By doing this, you however lose any benefit of using a `Task` in the first place, since just calling `Print` inside `Main` would do the same.

Comment: _"By doing this, you however lose any benefit of using a Task in the first place"_ - In OP's example, that's true, but that's not generally 100% true since you could do other stuff between the firing off of the task and the wait for it to complete.