# Console window not showing in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#

I have been using Visual Studio for quite some time and for the previous projects, I've been building them just fine, and the console window appeared normally. But with my new projects, it just flashes on for a second and then shuts down. I noticed that for the successfully built projects, the name of those projects would appear on the debugging button; but for the unsuccessfully build projects, there was just the word Start. Please help me with this issue. Thank you very much.[image: Successfully built][image: Unsuccessfully built]

Comment: add a `Console.ReadKey()` at the end. It's probably executing all of the code then exiting with code 0

Comment: Hey it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the console window closing immediately once displayed my output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868338/why-is-the-console-window-closing-immediately-once-displayed-my-output)