# Allow user input in CMD using C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I wanted to run CMD commands using C#. Therefore I copied some Code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;

            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();

            using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
            {
                if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("@echo off");
                    sw.WriteLine("title Test");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So. After I run some code like changing color etc, I want to enter normal cmd commands myself but the Window instantly closes.
Thanks for any Help :D

Comment: Your program has no reason to stay open, so it closes. Give it a reason to stay on (e.g. read input).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the console window closing immediately once displayed my output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868338/why-is-the-console-window-closing-immediately-once-displayed-my-output)

Answer (score 0):

Use ReadKey()

`Console.ReadKey()` Method makes the program wait for a key press and it prevents the screen until a key is pressed.